# Jenkins not generating JMeter HTML via Ant XSLT

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter

Jenkins is not generating JMeter HTML via Ant XSLT.
When I execute from the cmd prompt using the same build.xml, it's generating nice HTML Report.

I am not sure where am I missing. Please advise me!

See the below screenshots for the build.xml and Jenkins configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Please post code "as text".

Comment: Hi Jayan, It's not fitting the build.xml code here

Comment: Jayan,If you  click or double click on the Image,Image will open in new tab in bigger size

Comment: Why not publish the code somewhere else and provide snippet here?  Image cannot be copied down for comments/answers..

Comment: Your build.xml must  be using "current working directory" as the  base for output.  You can debug this by running ant in jenkins -- `ant -debug` or `ant -v`

Comment: Could you pleas guide me how to fix this.I mean where do I need to put build.xml .Its local Jenkins installed on same machine which I am using as master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call 'test' target in jenkins. You need to call 'all' in the 'Targets' field in Jenkins to call both `test` and `report`.

---

For detailed steps on using JMeter + Ant + Jenkins: Please check this - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/